# Using label properties/expression in ArcMap to label several ranges of numbers within feature class red?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, python-parser, expression

I have about a thousand labels, some of which need to be labeled red. For example, 511-533 and 659-671 need to be labeled red, and the rest can be labeled in black. They are all part of the same field and feature class. I've already used python to filter out the even numbers (different part of the work flow) and need to move on to coloring said number ranges. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to pre-filter your features to label them differently, just create two label classes - one for black labels and one for red. As in [this example](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/working-with-text/displaying-labels-using-label-classes-to-label-fea.htm), you can use SQL queries to separate the two groups.

Then you can use the [text symbol settings](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/working-with-text/displaying-labels-about-displaying-labels.htm#GUID-14315522-BF28-4A67-B3D2-F059472D09E1) to change the label colour for each class.